# Plotting box plot with 3 features

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, data-science

For example, I have a data frame like this

| x1 | x2 | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 0.3 | 0.4 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

How can I use boxplot to create a chart like this
[image]

To achieve a scatter plot, I seperate the dataframe into 2, based on `class` and plot them separately,on the same plot. But how to achieve something like the image above with boxplot?

Answer (score 0):

A box plot uses boxes and lines to depict the distributions of one or more groups of numeric data. This means the one axis must be categorical and the other numerical.

Refer to this link for more info: https://chartio.com/learn/charts/box-plot-complete-guide/

If still, you want to achieve this then you can bin one column.

Refer This: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html